# Javascript: how to name a IIFE

Tags: javascript, jquery, iife, self-invoking-function

Im working on a image slider plugin made in javascript! yes... I was bored
and I want it to kick off immediately so I tried to make a immediately invoking function expression (IIFE) like in the jQuery source code:

```
(function blahBlahBlah(someJquery, thing, lalala, jquery){
 //You could have no parameters if you'd wanted but for the sake of this question I just added some gibberish...
})(jQuery);
```

I tried to make a immediately invoking function expression (IIFE) like that and failed ::) this is what I've tried:

```
(function blahBlahBlah(someNames, someThing, lalala, Me){

})(MyName);
```

and failed but it works when I replace the last parameter with window?
I've even tried a left sided variable like this:

```
(function blahBlahBlah(someNames, someThing, lalala, Me){
 MyName = window;
})(MyName);
```

why does it do that and how can I get effect I'm looking for?
Thanks in advance,- Millzie.

Comment: "why does it do that" --- you're creating a function that accepts 4 argument, then pass only 1. What is the problem with it? "how can I get effect I'm looking for?" --- you haven't told what you are looking for

Comment: What's a "left sided variable"? (Note that this isn't a "self-invoking-function".)

Comment: @nnnnnn something like: page = window just basically variable without the var bit.

Comment: @zerkms I'm sorry if what I'm after its not clear but i basically want to name the last parameter of my iife.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you were trying to do works fine:

```
(function sayName(name) { console.log(name) } )('Millzie')
```

Comment: Probably better to not give the function the same name as the argument as that is just an opportunity for confusion.

Comment: @watson that's for the awesome and quick answer! Really made my day thanks.